# Why am I getting a NullPointerException in an if != null check

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

I have looked at many questions regarding this worn out question but I cannot find an answer for why I would be getting a NPE during my check for null. Myself and another partner are building a self-balancing binary search simply by using rotation so we need to store a temp Node if the new root has a child that needs to get placed on the opposite side.

Here we check if the nextRoots left or right child is null and if not we store it in a temp Node for future placement.

```
            Node temp = null;
            nextRoot = root.rightChild; // Set the next root
            oldRoot = root; // Hold the old root

            // If next roots left child is NOT null
            // Lets store it and null it now

            if (nextRoot.leftChild != null) // This check throws NPE, not nextRoot, just the nextRoot.leftChild
            {
                temp = nextRoot.leftChild;
                nextRoot.leftChild = null;
            }
```

I am under the impression that the if check should be the way to circumvent this problem but it in itself is causing the problem. Any help would be greatly appreciated and if you need more code please let me know.

Comment: `nextRoot` must be null.  Why is that a surprise to you?  There's no guarantee that the right child in a binary tree is not null.

Comment: I understand and that was my first thought but it is not, only the leftchild is null.

Comment: @Randallsm83: Have you tested this before making this statement? Never make assumptions like this when you don't yet know the cause of your error because you are most certainly wrong in your assumptions here.

Comment: Well I am terribly sorry, I tried with a System.out and wasn't getting a nextRoot null error but I blocked this in a check if nextRoot is null and I haven't gotten the error anymore.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the nextRoot.leftChild throws NPE... nextRoot is null.
Try to check if the code behavoiur is correct.
If it is... Modify the if like following:

`if (nextRoot != null && nextRoot.leftChild != null)`

Comment: Thank you everyone, I can't figure out why my previous didn't work for this but it appears this is definitely the problem, I will accept this answer as soon as my time limit is up.

Answer (score 2):

Check if `nextRoot` is not null in addition to `nextRoot.leftChild`

```
if (nextRoot != null && nextRoot.leftChild != null)
```

If you can debug this code, it is very easy to determine the cause rather than posting it in here.

Answer (score 1):

You must be getting NPE because the nextRoot is being set to null. Please check the line where nextRoot is set.